# c - loading raw binaries

Tags: c, operating-system, elf

Is it possible to execute a raw binary stored in a char array? I tried doing it like so:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(!f)
        return 1;
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    long l=ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    char *buf = malloc(l+1);
    fread(buf,1,l,f);
    fclose(f);
    void (*func)() = (void(*))buf;
    func();
}
```

but it only gives my segfaults. I'm working on my own OS (from scratch), so I'm getting rid of them.

Comment: You are getting rid of whom?

Comment: Why do you `malloc()` `l + 1`?

Comment: Dunno, I'm aware of getting rid of allocated memory

Comment: Ok, you`re "getting rid of " ".. segfaults" and ".. dynamic memory allocation". But your program does actually have both. Quite some work to do, right? For the question: as you are using your own OS, there will be little help why plain loading and calling a binary file does not work. Even more as you do not explain what format the file is, how it has been compiled, etc. [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) for instance, is a structured file format which requires a loader/relocator at least.

Comment: I'm not getting rid of ".. dynamic memory allocation", and in the question there is the format specification, "raw".

Comment: The file open format spec `"r"` is `read`, not `raw`.

Comment: As a sidenote: segfaults may be annoying, but they are actually a synptom, not the disease. That is badly written software.

Comment: Is your "OS" what you are loading and trying to run? If so isn't that the tail wagging the dog?

Comment: @WeatherVane, I'm not such stupid to think that "r" in fopen is for raw... I have input file in "RAW" binary format.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not thinking that segfaults are diseases, but I'm just getting rid of them after watching 100 of them.

Comment: You clearly stated to "get rid of segfaults". "Raw binary" is actually not a format specification, but the mode you read this file. It is something like calling the doc to ask what this strangely colored arey of skin on your arm would be.

Comment: @Olaf I got an ELF file, and objcopied it using `-O raw`. And everybody who is developing an OS wants to get rid of segfaults.

Comment: "r" might open the file in text mode actually. You might think of appending "b". But that depends on the stdlib and OS.

Comment: No, everyone developing an OS wants to catch segfaults and treat them correctly. Belive it or not, I've written some.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, actually I forgot to do that, but it didn't change anything. And what "format" is a function pointer cast to a char array?

Comment: Still not clear what sections are there, how are the relocated? When loaded to a malloc'ed array, how so you ensure the code's rellocated to exactly _that_ address? Similar for `.data`, `.const`, etc. All depending on the toolchain used to generate the original ELF.

Comment: Just to stat that clear: I do not want to discourage you, but for a starter, you might be better-off not to start with a PC, but with an embedded system. These are much easier to handle and you have everyting in your hands. A PC OTOH is an extremely complex beast not only for the hardware, but also for the software. For instance, you have to deal with the BIOS, PCIexpress, etc. There is a reason Linux has grown over the years that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do that but:

1. You cannot (in general) store your executable in the heap as your doing it here with `malloc` (nor in the stack for the same reason) because if your hardware supports it, your OS probably marks those areas as readable, writable but no executable (or at least it should do it).
2. You cannot just take the code of a compiled program, extract it to a file and expect to run it because it usually needs relocation, importing dynamic libraries, setting up another virtual memory area for the variables.

You could be able to do this with a simple handcrafted program which makes a system call to `exit(0)` ot prints "Hello World".

You might be able to use compiled code. For this, you would need to (at least):

- compile a self-contained program (no imported dynamic libraries, link the libraries statically and recompile those statically linked library);
- with position-independant code (`-fpic` of `-fpie`);
- without any relocation (maybe `-fvisibility=hidden` might help?).

If you manage to do this, you might be able to generate a raw file from the `PT_LOAD` sections of the ELF file. It would probably need to be executable, readable and writable (because you'll have code and data). And you will probably have to prepend an instruction to jump to the entry point which might be in the middle of the file.

You might look at how `ld.so` is compiled: it is expected to be loaded anywhere in the virtual address space and has a subset of itself which is supposed to be functional before relocations (because `ld.so` relocates itself as fare as I understand).

But you should probably just try to implement a basic ELF loader instead (and properly handle relocations).

Answer (score 5):

Apologies that this isn't exactly an answer but it's too long to fit as a comment...

I'm going to assume the intent of the file read with raw binary into a buffer is get code bytes into RAM, and you want to execute these bytes. Let's assume you've got the file I/O fixed, so now you have a buffer with code bytes. There's a few reasons why you could still segfault.

First, does your O/S implement virtual memory with page attributes such as read, write and execute? Most modern O/S's won't let you execute code on a page that isn't marked as code. (Marking pages this way is important to know what can be swapped and also to prevent malicious coding.)

Second, is the binary code you've loaded in fully relocatable? In other words, if the code has any JUMPs in it are they all relative? If there's any absolute JUMP ops in their then you need to run through a patch them up to line up where your buffer is in memory.

Third, is the binary code 100% self contained? If it calls out to any external functions then you need to patch those up, too.

Finally, does the binary code need to access data? If so, is all the data also in the binary and also relative addressed vs. absolute.

Comment: Is the entry position at the first address? Does the code conform to the caller's ABI? How about space for variables? Not just `.data`, but also `.bss`? Questions, questions. This is a more than optimistic approach.